# Get multiple outputs from different inputs (Model in multiple states)

Tags: excel

I have a model which has one input (the country selected) e.g. United Kingdom. Using SUMIFS I pull a bunch of data based on the country selection and then perform calculations on the data that is pulled. Very simplified analogy

- Selection: United Kingdom.
- Data Pulled: Population , GDP
- Calculation: GDP per Capita

I would like to collate the calculated output from the model for the range of countries I am working on. I could manually go through the model selecting each country and copying and pasting the data into a separate sheet, but this would mean that if I updated the underlying data, the collated data would be out of date.

Is there a way to query IF Country X was inputted into the model the output in cell y would be z.

In that way I could have table like this:

```
+----------------+----------------+--+
|    Country     | GBP Per Capita |  |
+----------------+----------------+--+
| United Kingdom | 10k            |  |
| United States  | 15K            |  |
| Ireland        | 8K             |  |
| ...            |                |  |
+----------------+----------------+--+
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but I believe you'll need VBA for that. Imagine every sheet looks as follows:

```
             A          B
1 Country name    Belgium
2 Population   11,000,000
3 Surface             ...
```

You can then write VBA code for making a summary, something like:

```
Sheets("Summary").Activate
For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  if ws.Name <> "Summary"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = ws.Range("B1").Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,1) = ws.Range("B2").Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,2) = ws.Range("B3").Value
    ...
  End if
Next
```

Then your summary sheet will look like:

```
Belgium    11,000,000  ...
France            ...  ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if I understand. So I have a model in one sheet where you can select the country from a drop down and it will run some calculations (sumifs etc.) based on that country.

What I would like to be able to do is on a separate sheet have the output the model would be giving me if x country was selected
            A                                    B                   
1 Country Name                        Cost
2 Belgium                                   500
3 United Kingdom                      1000
4 ....                                           ...

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question accordingly. And why can't you simple make a copy of that one worksheet so that you have two sheets with the calculations? One for real and one for testing purposes.

Comment: Have updated. The problem is that there 30+ countries and the worksheet becomes to big having duplicate sheets. Was wondering if there was another way